# How to update the data in one region through ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cakephp

i want to upload the data in one region of four links, when I clicked the link1 it will load the data in specific region, and when I clicked the link 2 it will load the page on the same region where first link open, how can I do that?

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="span-5">
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->Manager->link('Ecommerce',array('controller'=>'associations','action'=>"view_report"),array('id'=> 'home','class'=>'nav'));?></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home" class="nav">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="about" class="nav">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="contact" class="nav">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the data which I want to open from ecommerce link is int the newfile.ctp like that

```
 <?php v_start($this);?>

<h1><?php echo __l('View Report');?></h1>

<div class="firsttable">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <thead>
          <tr class="heading">
            <td><?php  echo __l('Financials');?></td>
            <td><?php  echo __l('Payment Methods');?></td>
            <td><?php  echo __l('By Credit Card');?></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>  

          <tr>
            <td>
                <?php 
                    echo __l("YTD \t ");
                    $ytd_total=0;
                    foreach ($YTD as $yearData)
                    {

                        $ytd_total +=$yearData['AssocPaymentDetail']['membership_fee'] - $yearData['AssociationDiscount']['amount'];

                    }
                    echo  $ytd_total."<br />";

                ?>
                <?php

                echo __l("Last 5days ");
                 $fda_total= 0;
                 foreach ($fiveDays as $fiveDaysData)
                    {

                        $fda_total += $fiveDaysData['AssocPaymentDetail']['membership_fee'] - $fiveDaysData['AssociationDiscount']['amount'];

                    }
                    echo $fda_total ."<br />";
                 ?> 
            </td>
            <td><?php  echo __l('creditcard');?>  <?php echo __l($ccSum) ?> </td>
            <td>
                <?php
        //       debug($paymentRecord);
        //      debug($ccIndex);
                    foreach($paymentRecord as $data =>$key){
                        foreach($ccIndex as $index){
                            if($data== $index)
                            {
                                echo "$data \t\t\t";
                                if(is_array($key))
                                    echo array_sum($key);
                                else 
                                    echo "\t\t $key";


                            }

                            echo "<br/>";
                        }   

                    }

                ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>  
    </table>
</div>
```

Please help me to do this, thanks in advance

Comment: is there any one who can answer of this question?

Comment: You can try `$('#regionID').load();`. Learn more here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Off topic, but you seem to be doing a lot of calculations inside your view. To improve your application, it's best to perform those kind of calculations in your models and only use the views for 'presentation'. Creating sums of records can be performed by your queries, you might need to use virtualFields for this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Answer (score 3):

Well I have done this without using any additional jquery

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="span-5">
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->Manager->link('Ecommerce',array('controller'=>'associations','action'=>"view_report"),array('update'=> '#testDiv'));?>li>
        <li><a href="#" id="home" class="nav">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="about" class="nav">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="contact" class="nav">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
 <div id = 'testdiv'></div>
```

The cake will update the region by itselp using the property update of cake. thanks a lot who answer that question, not matter answer is right or wrong. thanks all

Answer (score 1):

put in the links in href attribute and then handle them thru jquery something like this

```
$('a.nav').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
  $cont = $('[CONTAINERS SELECTOR]');
  $cont.html(data);
 })
})
```

EDIT-AFTER COMMENT

change your html to something like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="innerCont"></div>
    <div class="span-5">
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->Manager->link('Ecommerce',array('controller'=>'associations','action'=>"view_report"),array('id'=> 'home','class'=>'nav'));?></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="home" class="nav">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="about" class="nav">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="contact" class="nav">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and put the content selector to `div.innerCont`

```
$cont = $('div.innerCont');
```

Comment: can you please explain this line $cont = $('[CONTAINERS SELECTOR]'); where I can define [CONTAINERS SELECTOR]?

Comment: its the selector of the container in which you put in the html returned by the server

Comment: but my links are disappear to do that? I don't want to disappear the above links, these link will open in the specific region and the links will reain appear

Comment: but it loaded only the links not the data in the links.

Comment: I want to load the data which link exist for example if I clicked to home then the home data will come in the region.

Comment: can you please provide in the question what data is being returned on the ajax call

Comment: I have mentioned that data in the question

Answer (score 1):

you not specifie region in your html, here i'll assume it will be just after your ul node

```
$uls = $("ul.span5"); // select all page ul.span5
$uls.each(function(){ // for all ul.span5 node
    $ul = $(this); // current ul to work
    $region = $("<div/>").insertAfter($ul); // dynamic create and insert the region, as a div
    $links = $ul.find("a.nav"); // select all sub links
    $links.click(function(e){ // click on links
        $a = $(this); // current link
        var href = $a.attr("href"); // i assume you work on the href
        $region.load("myajax.php",{href:href},function(data){ // do ajax and load it in the common region
            // here load is done, do next step here
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // no real click please
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a single request handler to all links with `nav` as class name and then load the output to a container

```
$(".nav").on('click', function() {
    $("#loadingdiv").load("linktoload.php"); // or other 

});
```